# c# - Timer with different parameters at each time

Tags: c#, loops, timer

I have a list of few questions saved in a JSON file. I would like to send one different question every 10 seconds. 
I launched a timer every 10 seconds, but the int "position" cannot be incremented at each time. How could I do ?

```
public override void OnStart()
{
     dynamic data = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(File.ReadAllText("QCM.js"));

     int pos = 0;
     Timer aTimer = new Timer(2000);
     aTimer.Elapsed += (sender, e) => SendData(pos, data); 
     pos++;
     aTimer.Start();

static void SendData (int pos, dynamic data)
{
     PackageHost.WriteInfo(data.Data[pos].Label);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `pos` variable is captured by the lambda, you can use

```
aTimer.Elapsed += (sender, e) => SendData(pos++, data); 
//pos++;
```

Answer (score 0):

Make that `pos` a static variable, and increment it in `SendData`.

Be sure to end the timer when you run out of data.

Comment: It is not possible to make pos static in this function.